# orderID is not auto-incrementing, my orderID is always the same

Tags: php, sql

I am creating a grocery store for school and for each order I create it is  supposed to grab a unique orderID from a database. I am supposed to be able let the user view unique orders using the orderID so the fact that it is always the same is a problem. to The orderID is set to auto increment but every time I submit an order it uses the same orderID. Here is my code

```
$email = $_SESSION['email'];
$name = $_SESSION['firstname'];
$shipping = $_SESSION['shipping'];
$ordertotal = $_SESSION['ordertotal'];
$tax = $_SESSION['tax'];
$productid = $_SESSION['productid'];
$count = $_SESSION['itemquantity'];
$linetotal = $_SESSION['linetotal'];

//get customer id
$custID = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT CustomerID FROM Customers WHERE 
Email ='$email' AND FirstName ='$name'   ");
$customerid = mysqli_fetch_assoc($custID);
foreach($customerid as $i)
//print_r($i);

//insert customer id
$insertcustID = mysqli_query($connection, "INSERT INTO Orders (CustomerID) 
VALUES ('$i') ");

//get order id
$orderid = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT OrderID FROM Orders
WHERE CustomerID = '$i'
AND OrderDate IS NULL"); 
$id = mysqli_fetch_assoc($orderid);
foreach($id as $r)
print_r($r);

//get date
date_default_timezone_set("UTC");
$mydate=getdate(date("U"));
foreach($mydate as $d)
//echo "$mydate[weekday], $mydate[month] $mydate[mday], $mydate[year]";

//insert the order
$setOrder = mysqli_query($connection, "UPDATE Orders SET
ShippingCost='$shipping', Tax='$tax', Total='$ordertotal', OrderDate=' $d ’
WHERE OrderID='$r'
AND CustomerID='$i' ");

$insertOrder = mysqli_query($connection, "INSERT INTO OrderDetails
(OrderID, ProductID, Quantity, LineTotal)
VALUES ('$r', '$productid', '$count', '$linetotal')");

$allorders = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM OrderDetails");
foreach($allorders as $q)
print_r($q);

unset($_SESSION["cart"]); //resets cart after order is submitted

include("realfooter.html");
```

Comment: you can put the code's Orders table from mysql for check your conf

Comment: Your foreach is missing brackets not sure that has anything to do with the issue but can cause some really odd behavior. Likewise we need to see your SQL that creates the Order Table.

Comment: `foreach($customerid as $i)` seams weird. `$customerid` would be an array looking like: `['CustomerId' => 123]` (since `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` only returns _one_ record) so you can access the customer id directly without a foreach loop.

Comment: Every single foreach is actually missing their braces. Here's the manual about foreach: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php. I would suggest you read through it. I would also recommend going through some basic PHP + MySQL tutorials.

Comment: OK I added brackets to the for each statements, it didn't change anything, also if I set the values for the sqli query to $customerid it just gives me a Array to string conversion error. Also I do not have access to the code of the database.

Answer (score 0):

oh ... it seems $i is a local variable , you declare $i variable inside foreach

```
foreach($customerid as $i)
//print_r($i);

//insert customer id
$insertcustID = mysqli_query($connection, "INSERT INTO Orders (CustomerID) 
VALUES ('$i') ");

//get order id
$orderid = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT OrderID FROM Orders
WHERE CustomerID = '$i'
```

you try put a temporary variable outside foreach, It will store the value of the variable

```
$customer_id ="";
foreach($customerid as $i) {
//print_r($i);
    $customer_id = $i;
//insert customer id
    $insertcustID = mysqli_query($connection, "INSERT INTO Orders (CustomerID) 
VALUES ('$i') ");
}
//get order id
$orderid = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT OrderID FROM Orders
WHERE CustomerID = '$customer_id'
AND OrderDate IS NULL");
```

Or set LIMIT for  $custID

```
//get customer id
$custID = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT CustomerID FROM Customers WHERE 
Email ='$email' AND FirstName ='$name'  LIMIT =1 ");
$customerid = mysqli_fetch_assoc($custID);
//insert customer id
    $insertcustID = mysqli_query($connection, "INSERT INTO Orders (CustomerID) 
VALUES ('".$customerid['CustomerID']."') ");

//get order id
$orderid = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT OrderID FROM Orders
WHERE CustomerID = '".$customerid['CustomerID']."'
AND OrderDate IS NULL");
$id = mysqli_fetch_assoc($orderid);
foreach($id as $r)
    print_r($r);
```